# How to change the name of an app?

Tags: titanium

My client want a the danish letter 'Ø' in the appname. When I create a new Titanium project containing this letter in the name then the project cannot compile:

```
[INFO] Performing clean build
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.2/iphone/builder.py", line 1148, in main
    execute_xcode("iphonesimulator%s" % link_version,["GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS=__LOG__ID__=%s DEPLOYTYPE=development TI_DEVELOPMENT=1 DEBUG=1 TI_VERSION=%s %s" % (log_id,sdk_version,debugstr)],False)
  File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.2/iphone/builder.py", line 1066, in execute_xcode
    output = run.run(args,False,False,o)
  File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.2/iphone/run.py", line 39, in run
    sys.exit(rc)
SystemExit: 65
```

Is there an alternative way to set the app name?  Preferable if I could use ascii letters in all filenames/dirnames, so it is easier to store in git.

Any ideas?

I wanted to ask this question on the Q&A forum on appcelerator, but the "Post Question" button doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can update the name from info.plist file

Comment: If you mean the "post question" button after writing the question on their forum, you need to first preview the question before you can post it.

Comment: @Shauna, thank you. I was confused and have now figured out how to post on appcelerator. The way of adding tags was somehow not obvious to me, and the post button gets enabled when adding a few tags.

Comment: @Muhammad Zeeshan, thank you. I have successfully changed the name in the Info.plist as you said, but would also like to change name on Android. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**iPhone:** For renaming your app name you can update info.plist.

**Android:** You have to add these lines in your tiapp.xml file. The label tag holds the app name.

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <manifest>

            <application android:debuggable="false" android:icon="@drawable/appicon" android:label="YourAppName" >


            </application>  
        </manifest>
</android>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I use special danish letters in the tiapp.xml file. [ERROR] UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf8' in position 328: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: I have now created a custom AndroidManifest.xml file, which works. Whenever I used special danish letters Titanium failed to compile the project. Yes. the tiapp.xml is in utf8.

Answer (score 5):

As of Titanium SDK 3.x for **both iOS & Android**:

1. In your project, Open `/i18n/` folder, select the language you'd like the App name to be in, example: `/i18n/en/` folder.
2. Add a file named: `app.xml` with:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <resources>
       <string name="appname">NAME OF APP IN THIS LANGUAGE</string>
   </resources>`

Comment: I wonder if stackoverflow should give the chance to reselect a proper answer as time goes by, clearly this answer should be the correct answer for now, the later one might have been the correct one at that time, it ain't not anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The tiapp.xml file was not happy about special danish letters, so I ended up creating a custom `platform/android/AndroidManifest.xml` file. In this file there was no problems using special danish letters.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="dk.topmodel.2011" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <!-- TI_MANIFEST -->

    <application android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:label="Topmodel" android:name="Topmodel_2011Application"
        android:debuggable="false">

        <!-- TI_APPLICATION -->

        <activity android:name=".Topmodel_2011Activity"
            android:label="Topmodel" android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="ti.modules.titanium.map.TiMapActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
        />
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiTranslucentActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiModalActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
        />
        <activity android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.TiTabActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.android.TiPreferencesActivity" />

        <service android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.analytics.TiAnalyticsService"
            android:exported="false" />


    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


</manifest>
```